# Android: Clean Master App gives message "your application restarted 9 times in 5 minutes()"

Tags: android

I am getting a message like "your application restarted 9 times in 5 minutes()", when I tried to clean Junk Files using "Clean Master" application.

Please find the screenshot for this issue. I am not able to figure out why this message is coming. Any idea on this???

[image: CleanMaster_Issue]

Comment: What is your application?

Comment: It has functionalities like uploading images, displaying images, Push notifications after uploading etc. User can upload images from device or he can use Camera then crop it and then upload. Basic functionality is this much only.

Comment: @user1182217 Usually i don't trust those app (Clean Master and co.). You can check if there is something wrong with Developer Console or, more deeply, with Fabric (aka Crashlytics).

Comment: Any body knows how these Clean Master kind of Apps work? Please share. Based on that may be i can figure out the real cause!!!

Answer (score 0):

These apps may have once been useful but the Android has progressed far enough that they are now outdated, unnecessary and rather harmful.

On Windows, you want to keep as much RAM as possible as you can so that programs have enough room to operate. When RAM fills up, Windows is forced to start using hard drive space as virtual RAM and hard drives are much slower than physical RAM.

This is not true for Android.

Android’s operating system has its own native handler for assigning RAM to apps and making sure that all of it is being used in the most optimal way. In fact, Android purposely tries to keep apps loaded into RAM for better performance. RAM is fast, remember? On mobile devices, every bit of speed is critical for a good user experience, so keeping apps in RAM is actually a good thing.

Not only does Android handle RAM assignment, but it also keeps track of background apps so they don’t use up unnecessary processor resources. There’s no noticeable performance hit for leaving apps loaded in RAM.

App killers, memory boosters, performance enhancers, etc all claim wiping memory will speed up the phone. With current versions of Android, that's simply not true. It's actually the opposite. What will happen is the task killer app kills other apps which use resources to process. Then the OS restarts those, or other apps to fill the memory again, which takes even more resources. The task killer app kills again and the process repeats over and over. So in reality, those kinds of apps reduce performance and increase battery usage by restarting apps again and again. Remember, those dormant apps don't consume any additional battery or CPU in the first place.